# FindNode with two equals node

Tags: xml, delphi

I created a WebService that generate XML according to MySQL rows and the result is this:

```
<DB>
    <CONFIG>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <CODAUTORIZACAO>12345</CODAUTORIZACAO>
        <CODUSUARIO>12345</CODUSUARIO>
        <CODEMPRESA>12345</CODEMPRESA>
        <NOMEEMPRESA>TESTE</NOMEEMPRESA>
    </CONFIG>
    <COLETEIROS>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <CODIGO>123</CODIGO>
        <NOME>teste</NOME>
        <PRECOCX>1</PRECOCX>
        <PRECOKG>1</PRECOKG>
        <PRECOCS>1</PRECOCS>
    </COLETEIROS>
    <COLETEIROS>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <CODIGO>135</CODIGO>
        <NOME>ab</NOME>
        <PRECOCX>12</PRECOCX>
        <PRECOKG>321</PRECOKG>
        <PRECOCS>12</PRECOCS>
    </COLETEIROS>
</DB>
```

If you see, this XML has two node with same name **"COLETEIROS"**, but when I find node with **XMLDocument.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.FindNode('COLETEIROS')** I only able to see the first one. Is there a way to FindNode while exist? I am trying to fill combobox with this values but I'm new with XMLDocument.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Iterate over the nodes

Comment: I didnt found anything about Iterate to Delphi XMLDocument, only for C# and Delphi NativeXML, but in Delphi XE10 NativeXML was substitued to XMLDocument and I dont know the equivalent code cause I dont know both haha :/

Comment: All the XML libraries allow enumeration

Comment: Thanks for help! I found another way to do it, but you helped too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where there are multiple child nodes **FindNode** will only return the first of any specified node.  **FindNode** returns an *IXMLNode*.

To obtain a list of all nodes with the specified name, use the **selectNodes()** method of the **IDOMNode** interface. **selectNodes()** returns an *IDOMNodeList*.  You can then iterate over the node list as you would normally.

```
  uses
    XMLDoc,
    XMLDOM,
    XMLIntf;

procedure ExampleUsingSelectNodes;
const
  XML = '<DB>'
      + '    <CONFIG>'
      + '        <ID>1</ID>'
      + '        <CODAUTORIZACAO>12345</CODAUTORIZACAO>'
      + '        <CODUSUARIO>12345</CODUSUARIO>'
      + '        <CODEMPRESA>12345</CODEMPRESA>'
      + '        <NOMEEMPRESA>TESTE</NOMEEMPRESA>'
      + '    </CONFIG>'
      + '    <COLETEIROS>'
      + '        <ID>1</ID>'
      + '        <CODIGO>123</CODIGO>'
      + '        <NOME>teste</NOME>'
      + '        <PRECOCX>1</PRECOCX>'
      + '        <PRECOKG>1</PRECOKG>'
      + '        <PRECOCS>1</PRECOCS>'
      + '    </COLETEIROS>'
      + '    <COLETEIROS>'
      + '        <ID>2</ID>'
      + '        <CODIGO>135</CODIGO>'
      + '        <NOME>ab</NOME>'
      + '        <PRECOCX>12</PRECOCX>'
      + '        <PRECOKG>321</PRECOKG>'
      + '        <PRECOCS>12</PRECOCS>'
      + '    </COLETEIROS>'
      + '</DB>';
var
  doc: TXMLDocument;
  select: IDOMNodeSelect;
  nodes: IDOMNodeList;
begin
  doc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  doc.LoadFromXML(XML);

  select := doc.DocumentElement.DOMNode as IDOMNodeSelect;
  nodes  := select.selectNodes('COLETEIROS');

  // At this point nodes is an IDOMNodeList with length 2 (i.e. contains both COLETEIROS nodes)

  // process the list of nodes here
end;
```

Alternatively you could iterate over each child node in your document and test each one for the required node name and only process the ones that match the name you want.  This is more long-winded but works entirely with the **XMLDoc** interfaces without requiring DOM support (which may or may not be important in your case).

Assuming the same XML const declaration for the example XML document in this case, the code for manual iteration would be something like:

```
var
  doc: TXMLDocument;
  node: IXMLDOMNode;
begin
  doc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  doc.LoadFromXML(XML);

  node := doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.First;
  while Assigned(node) do
  begin
    if node.NodeName = 'COLETEIROS' then
    begin
      // Do something with this node
    end;
    node := node.NextSibling
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

`FindNode()` cannot be used to search for multiple nodes.  You will have to either:

1. loop through all the nodes manually looking for the individual `COLETEIROS` nodes:

   ```
   var
     Node: IXMLNode;
     I: Integer;

   for I := 0 to XMLDocument.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Count-1 do
   begin
     Node := XMLDocument.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[I];
     if Node.LocalName = 'COLETEIROS' then
        ...
   end;
   ```
2. use an XPath query:

   ```
   var
     XPath: IDOMNodeSelect;
     Nodes: IDOMNodeList;
     Node: IDOMNode;
     I: Integer;

   if Supports(XMLDocument.DocumentElement, IDOMNodeSelect, XPath) then
   begin
     Nodes := XPath.selectNodes('/DB/COLETEIROS');
     for I := 0 to Nodes.length-1 do
     begin
       Node := Nodes[I];
       ...
     end;
   end;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

***Update:*** To have this solution work, you will need to create a custom inheritance of the `IXMLNodeList` interface and the `TXMLNodeList` class.
This is in order to expose the `protected function InternalInsert(Index: Integer; const Node: IXMLNode): Integer;` method which ignores the AOwner assignment checks of the `IXMLNodeList.Insert` method.

I use a helper function to retrieve a list of all nodes with a given name.

I use the `ChildNodes[I].CloneNode(True)` method so that I'm not accidentally editing active data.
The method in this case is simply for viewing a list of nodes of given name.

```
type
  IXMLNodeListCustom = interface(IXMLNodeList)
    ['{9F2AB4AD-D8DD-41AE-85AA-8D33D0D156C9}']
    function InternalInsert(Index: Integer; const Node: IXMLNode): Integer;
  end;

  TXMLNodeListCustom = class(TXMLNodeList, IXMLNodeListCustom);

implementation

class function TXMLUtils.GetNodesByName(const aNode: IXMLNode; const aName: string): IXMLNodeList;
var
  I: Integer;
  resultList : IXMLNodeListCustom;
begin
  Result := nil;

  if aNode <> nil then
  begin
    resultList := TXMLNodeListCustom.Create(nil, '', nil);
    for I := 0 to aNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if aNode.ChildNodes[I].NodeName = aName then
      begin
        resultList.InternalInsert(-1, aNode.ChildNodes[I].CloneNode(True));
      end;
    end;
    Result := resultList as IXMLNodeList;
  end;
end;
```

Usage:

```
var
  dbNode : IXMLNode;
  coleteirosNodes : IXMLNodeList;

coleteirosNodes := TXMLUtils.GetNodesByName(dbNode, 'COLETEIROS');

// Assignment checking for your own sanity
if coleteirosNodes <> nil then
begin
  // do required work - remembering that data in list is not linked to dbNode
  // it is a copy of the data
end;
```

I am not a fan of having to extend classes this way but I had to do this because of the following assignment check within the standard Insert method

```
if Assigned(Owner.ParentNode) and (Owner.HostNode = nil) and
   (doNodeAutoIndent in Owner.OwnerDocument.Options) and
   not (Node.NodeType in [ntText, ntAttribute]) then
begin
```

There is no check for `Assigned(Owner)`. Using the InternalInsert allows you to add items to the list without needing an Owner.

Iterating over `dbNode.childNodes` and having an additional `if dbNode.childNodes[I].NodeName = aName then` inside of the for loop is simpler, but I like helper methods.